# How can set visibility off text-view in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a article application where there are different categories that are shown in navigation drawer.
I had set a text-view for all my fragment but i need when my first fragment that is on displaypostion = 0 that time my text-view will be visibility should be hide and when other fragment are open the text-view property goes to visible. here is my code -

```
public class MainActivitySlider extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_slider);
    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customactionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8")));
    Typeface fontt = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "helvetica.ttf");
    mTitleTextView.setTypeface(fontt);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setIcon(
               new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
    final TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface fontt1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "helvetica.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(fontt1);
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos

    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.dd2, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            if()
            txt.setText(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //txt.setText(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
         @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }

}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main3, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_location_found:
        hidetext(); 
    return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void hidetext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivitySlider.this, SearchResultsActivity
            .class);
    startActivity(i);

}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new OneFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new TwoFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you wants to hide these mTitleTextView,

```
switch (position) {
case 0:
    mTitleTextView.setText("");
    mTitleTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    fragment = new OneFragment();
    break;
case 1:
    mTitleTextView.setText("");
    mTitleTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fragment = new TwoFragment();
    break;

default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: thanks! its working fine but when i go from one category to another the visibility is slow it take few second and in between that time it show the previous text that set to it.

Comment: I have made updates about previous text issue, but I don't have idea about slow visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check this out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

Possible values:
[View.VISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE), [View.INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE), [View.GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)